# How to set android:angle property of GradientDrawable programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, gradient

This is my color list :

```
static ArrayList<Integer> colors;
static {
    colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#43CFCF"));
    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#1C6E9B"));
    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#AC88C0"));
    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#EE5640"));
    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#EFBF4D"));
}
```

And this is my drawable array :

```
static Drawable[] drawables;
static {
    drawables = new Drawable[5];
    drawables[0] = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TL_BR,  new int[]{colors.get(0), colors.get(1)});
    drawables[1] = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TL_BR,  new int[]{colors.get(1), colors.get(2)});
    drawables[2] = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TL_BR,  new int[]{colors.get(2), colors.get(3)});
    drawables[3] = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TL_BR,  new int[]{colors.get(3), colors.get(4)});
    drawables[4] = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TL_BR,  new int[]{colors.get(4), colors.get(0)});
}
```

Now, I am iterating over the drawable[], and cross fading b/w nth and (n+1)th drawables, using alpha animation.

Now this is how my layout looks like :

[image]

My layout is rectangular (GradientDrawable.Orientation : Topleft-BottomRight), but this orientation value is not setting my gradient line (between the colors) from the top-right bound to bottom-left bound of my rectangle. It would work perfectly if my layout is of SquareShape.

So I would like to set angle (trial-and-error), of each GradientDrawable programmatically (cannot use xml, since I am creating drawables in code, otherwise I would have to create 5 xmls, one for each drawable).

Also, how does the value of android:angle work, if my orientation is TL_BR ? Does the angle changes with reference (axis) to TL_BR line (at 0 radians).

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
drawables[0] = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TL_BR,  new int[]{colors.get(0), colors.get(1)});
```

Instead of:

```js
drawables[0] = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TL_BR,  new int[]{colors.get(0), colors.get(1)});
```